# SQL Query to Show Distinct Values Joined with their Count

Tags: sql, join, count, distinct

enter code hereI would like to run a sql query to show distinct values along with their count.
More specifically, my table that keeps track of user activity contains the following columns:

```
userId, NumberOfSources,Source
```

I would like to see the distinct sources for each user in the last week, sorted by the number of these distinct values.
For exmaple, desired output should look like:

```
userId   |   NumberOfSources   | Source
user1    |   3                 | sourceA
user1    |   3                 | sourceB
user1    |   3                 | sourceC
user2    |   2                 | sourceD
user2    |   2                 | sourceE
```

I'm able to run a query to show each of those two columns but couldn't combine them.

Show number of distinct values:

```
SELECT userId, count(distinct source) FROM myTable GROUP BY userId ORDER BY count(distinct source) desc limit 10
```

Show distinct values:

```
SELECT distinct source, userId FROM myTable limit 10
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks,
Ori.

Comment: Maybe it requires a Join query?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT userId, count(source) 
  FROM myTable GROUP BY userId 
  ORDER BY count(distinct source) desc limit 10
  Group by userId
```

Comment: This only shows the number of (non-distinct?) sources for each user, but doesn't show the sources themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Updated ON 23-12-2013

select userId,count(source) NumberOfSources,Source from myTable group by Source,userId order by UserID,count(source) desc

--  SELECT userId, count(source) NumberOfSources,Source 
--  FROM myTable GROUP BY userId,Source 
--  ORDER BY userId,count(source) desc,Source limit 10

Comment: That would count the number of appearances for each source for the user, rather than the number of sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT userId, COUNT(source),source
 FROM myTable
 GROUP BY  userId ,source
 ORDER BY COUNT(source) DESC
```

Comment: That would count the number of appearances for each source for the user, rather than the number of sources.